# Align text to left/start within a div within a material ui Box

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, inline-styles

I am trying to get this field's error handling ui[image: wrong error handling layout] to render like this field's error handling ui

[image: correct error handling layout]

Note that in the correct (second) ui example, the error text is shown at the left.  Ignoring the text color or and text font for now - how do I make the darn text ("asset bundle url is not valid....") align to the left?

My current styles

```
hr: {
    border: '1px solid red'
  },
  errorDiv: {
    align: "left",
    flexDirection: 'column',
  }
```

and where it is used in the code

```
<Box>
        <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
          <Button
            size="small"
            variant={'outlined'}
            color={'default'}
            onClick={() => {
              // eslint-disable-next-line
              (uploadInputRef?.current as any)?.click();
            }}
          // disabled={isDisabled ? true : false}
          >
            {url ? 'Change Asset Bundle' : 'Add Asset Bundle'}
          </Button>
        </label>
        {error ? (
          <div className={classes.errorDiv}>
            <hr className={classes.hr}></hr>
            {error}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </Box>
```

The Box is wrapped in an unstyled div.  The component is wrapped in a Grid item component at the next level up.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I got it.

Used mui `FormHelperText`!  (I continue to underestimate the breadth of MUI.)

```js
import FormHelperText from '@mui/material/FormHelperText';

...

<Box>
  <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
    <Button
      size="small"
      variant={'outlined'}
      color={'default'}
      onClick={() => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        (uploadInputRef?.current as any)?.click();
      }}
      // disabled={isDisabled ? true : false}
      >
    {url ? 'Change Asset Bundle' : 'Add Asset Bundle'}
    </Button>
  </label>
  {error ? (
    <div className={classes.errorDiv}>
      <hr className={classes.hr}></hr>
      <FormHelperText >{error}</FormHelperText>
    </div>
  ) : null}
</Box>
```